# flume command stuck for sequence generator creation

Tags: hadoop, flume

Below is my conf file and when I run the flume start command  I am unable to get any response after the below step in the log. Could you please review and help me what I did wrong and how to correct ?

`seq_gen.conf` file details and error logs:

```
# Naming the components on the current agent 

SeqGenAgent.sources = SeqSource   
SeqGenAgent.channels = MemChannel 
SeqGenAgent.sinks = HDFS 

# Describing/Configuring the source 
SeqGenAgent.sources.SeqSource.type = seq

# Describing/Configuring the sink
SeqGenAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs 
SeqGenAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/user/Hadoop/seqgen_data/
SeqGenAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.filePrefix = log 
SeqGenAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
SeqGenAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 100
SeqGenAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream 

# Describing/Configuring the channel 
SeqGenAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory 
SeqGenAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 1000 
SeqGenAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100 

# Binding the source and sink to the channel 
SeqGenAgent.sources.SeqSource.channels = MemChannel
SeqGenAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel 

Logs:
hare/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.1-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib-examples:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/sources:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/*' -Djava.library.path=:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/lib org.apache.flume.node.Application --conf-file /usr/local/flume/conf/seq_gen.conf --name SeqGenAgent
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/flume/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-2.0.0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

No response after this line once i run the below command. Could you please help.

```
hduser@kumar:/usr/local/flume/bin$ ./flume-ng agent --conf /usr/local/flume/conf  --conf-file /usr/local/flume/conf/seq_gen.conf --name SeqGenAgent
```

Comment: This question doesn't have enough information to provide an answer.  The config is helpful as is the command, but the logs don't show anything.  Does the command just hang?  Does it return to a prompt directly?  (If so, what return code from `echo $?`)  In a separate terminal can you see the `flume-ng` agent running using `ps aux` or similar?  Edit the question with these details and any other diagnosis -- what have you tried, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Get your hostname using the following command

> hostname

Then, edit the following line in seq_gen.conf

> SeqGenAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://**[output from hostname here]**:9000/user/Hadoop/seqgen_data/